# How can I pack one library into another JS library using npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am creating an angular library, which is internally using the vtk.js library. I tried adding vtk.js as a peer dependency. But on installing my custom package, it is showing a warning to install vtk.js as well.

Is there any way I can make sure that the vtk.js package will also get packed inside my angular package?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will be better if you can show your attempt, error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can express dependencies of your library in a 2 ways (actually 3 but `devDependencies` is pretty self-explained so we omit them)

1. `peerDependencies` - you can use this type of dependency if you need to express the following things:

- Your library is depends on some **specific** version of another library
- Your library will have a conflicts in case `node_module` contains **few versions of the dependency** (because of so called transitive dependency this case is possible)
- You wish a developer decide on what version of the dependency to use

As you mentioned `peerDependencies` is not installed automatically, instead it will warn a consumer of you lib about missing dependency or incompatible version of it

2.`dependencies` - use dependencies if you do not care about the cases described above. Having `vtk.js` here guarantee that it will be installed automatically for every consumer of your lib